# Multiple Scaleboxes Inside TikZ Graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I created the following graph with vector symbol on edges:
[image]

I want to make the vectors larger without enlarging the text, so I devised a command:

```
\newcommand{\vecb}[1]{\reflectbox{\reflectbox{\scalebox{2}[1.5]{\ensuremath{\vec{\scalebox{0.5}[0.66]{\ensuremath{#1}}}}}}}}
```

Which makes the arrow larger:

[image]

But if I use it in TikZ, it errors:

> Use of \XKV@resa doesn't match its definition.

Graph code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
  \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={rectangle}}

  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{John}
  \Vertex[x=4.5,y=0]{London}
  \Vertex[x=9,y=0]{England}
  \Edge[style={->,>=triangle 45},label=$\vec{residence}$](John)(London)
  \Edge[style={->,>=triangle 45},label=$\vec{capital}$](London)(England)
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Why doesn't this work? How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using normal tikz with the `positioning` library, this can be simpler. I used a small trick to get the arrow using `$\overrightarrow{..}$`. This arrows extends over the entire content, so I included only three letters inside the braces like this, `$ca\overrightarrow{pit}al$` such that the arrow becomes only three characters long.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[blk/.style={draw, minimum height=2em}, >=triangle 45,thick]
\node(j) [blk]{John}; 
\node(l) [blk,right=10em of j]{London}; 
\node(e) [blk,right=10em of l]{England};

\draw [->] (j) -- node[fill=white]{$res\overrightarrow{ide}nce$} (l);
\draw [->] (l) -- node[fill=white]{$ca\overrightarrow{pit}al$} (e);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to TeX.SE! So you are using Ti*k*Z and are afraid that you cannot add an arrow on top of some node text? No, I don't think there is an issue. ;-)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-graph}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[vec/.style={inner ysep=3pt,path picture={
 \draw[-latex,line width=0.4pt] ([yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=3pt]path picture bounding box.north west)
 --([yshift=-1.5pt,xshift=-3pt]path picture bounding box.north east);}}]
  \GraphInit[vstyle=Normal]
  \SetGraphUnit{1.5}
  \tikzset{VertexStyle/.append style={rectangle}}

  \Vertex[x=0,y=0]{John}
  \Vertex[x=4.5,y=0]{London}
  \Vertex[x=9,y=0]{England}
  \Edge[style={->,>=triangle 45},label=$residence$,labelstyle=vec](John)(London)
  \Edge[style={->,>=triangle 45},label=$capital$,labelstyle=vec](London)(England)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I personally would not use math font for `residence`/`capital`.

Comment: This is not the type I arrow I want, besides, it looks tiny in the way I show the figure. Using `\protect` solves the issue of using the arrow I want, I just don't know why.

Answer (score 3):

pure `tikz` solution, vectors' arrows are drawn with `tikz`:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.141592mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, chains, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 33mm,
  start chain = A going right,
   arr/.style = {very thick, -Triangle},
   lbl/.style = {rectangle, fill=white, name=lbl, inner ysep=3mm,
                 path picture={
                 \draw[thick, -{Straight Barb[length=0.8mm,width=1.2mm]}]
                 ([shift={(-.2,-.15)}]lbl.north) -- ([shift={(.2,-.15)}]lbl.north);}
                },
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, on chain=A, join=by arr}
                    ]
\node[box] {John};
\node[box] {London};
\node[box] {England};
\path   (A-1) -- node[lbl] {\textit{residence}}  (A-2)
        (A-2) -- node[lbl] {\textit{capital}}    (A-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This might be another solution using `tikz-cd`. For an small arrow you can use (for example) the suggestion of @AboAmmar.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
\boxed{\text{John}} \arrow[rr, "\overrightarrow{\mathit{residence}}" description] &  & \boxed{\text{London}} \arrow[rr, "\overrightarrow{\mathit{capital}}" description] &  & \boxed{\text{England}}
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```